# vscode didn't close all django processes when comment "--noreload"

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

VSCode Version: 1.42.1
OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Comment "--noreload" in launch.json
2. Press Ctrl + F5 to run the django process.
3. Click "stop(Shift + F5)" button to stop all django processes.
4. But there is still a process (pid 23069) that has not been closed.
5. And its parent process become 1 from 23064

[image]

Comment: Please try the latest version of the debugger to see if that fixes things https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/2104

Comment: @BrettCannon Lastest version doesn't work, unless add --noreload in launch.json

Comment: Then please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd.